# Significance of SMALL_PRIME_PRODUCT in BigInteger

Tags: java

What is the significance of the below listed variable in BigInteger class and why does this have these specific prime number multiplied?

```
private static final BigInteger SMALL_PRIME_PRODUCT  = valueOf(3L*5*7*11*13*17*19*23*29*31*37*41);
```

Comment: Is this a programming question or a math question?

Comment: They skipped two (literally 2). Otherwise it's the first twelve primes. And, is exactly as described, the product of small primes.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch. is 13th prime number and beyond not considered small prime?

Comment: There are an infinite number of primes, all I can say for sure is the value `152125131763605L` is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). As are the values that produce it.